# Can you get a dragon head by killing it with charged creepers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

According to Minecraft Wiki, I can get heads from killing a mob using Charged Creepers (except for wither skeletons). However, is there a way for me to get Dragon heads by killing Ender Dragons with creepers? I wanted to ask before I try as I did not want my efforts to be wasted.(my trident is breaking)

Any help on this question will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact it's not possible can also be verified by looking at the Ender Dragon's loot table in the default datapack which has the following content:

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:entity"
}
```

I.e. no item drops at all. You should be able to enable it with a loot table such as this one:

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:entity",
  "pools": [
    {
      "rolls": 1.0,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "name": "minecraft:dragon_head"
        }
      ],
      "conditions": [
        {
          "condition": "minecraft:entity_properties",
          "predicate": {
            "type": "minecraft:creeper",
            "nbt": "{Charged:1b}"
          },
          "entity": "killer"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, the only way to obtain dragon heads are from the End city ships.

On death, the Ender dragon can only give a dragon egg (for the first dragon death only),
spawn an end gateway at the end of the main island (one new gateway spawns in per dragon death, which caps out at 20),
and varying amounts of exp. orbs, with the amount depending on whether it was the first death or a following death (the dragon drops 12000 exp. on its first death, and drops only 500 in future deaths).

It's unlikely that charged creepers are able to effect the Ender dragon's drops, since the dragon's drops are more about spawning certain blocks in the world and exp. orbs, rather than actual items.

Comment: The dragon drops 12K xp on first kill, and 500 on subsequent kills. Also, there can be **at most** 20 gateways at the end island. Each dragon kill spawns one gateway, until there are 20 cap.

Comment: What are the different gateways for? Don't you only need one?

Comment: @Big_Chungus Each gateway takes you to a different spot on the outer islands. You technically don't need any, since you can also get there by flying machine.

Answer (score 2):

No. I tested this by traveling to the end and typing `/execute at @e[type=minecraft:ender_dragon,limit=1] run summon minecraft:creeper ~ ~ ~ {powered:1b,ExplosionRadius:30b,Fuse:0,ignited:1b}`.

This summoned a charged creeper that killed the enderdragon instantly. The dragon did not drop a head.

Answer (score -1):

I'm 65% sure it wouldn't work. but it might. I think it's likely that the only way to get them is the front end of end city ships.

Comment: End ships are quite rare though... Therefore I want to get dragon heads the more efficient way

Comment: Currently, on my seed, I did not find any end ships...

Comment: @DREADLORD XD you could use the Chunk Base website to find where End cities are in your End dimension.    Chunk Base is a commonly used website to find where specific biomes and structures are in different world seeds, update versions (it can go from 1.3 to 1.16 if I could recall), dimensions, and editions of the game (Java, Bedrock, and Discontinued Console).    Upon searching "Chunk base end city finder" on Google search, I was able to find the website quite easily.    If you'd like a link to the End city finder for convenience sake: https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/endcity-finder

Comment: your welcome. still, it may work, I'm just saying that it *probably* will not work.